# Number Theory and p-Remainder Numbers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

In order to submit the problem, here it comes the definition we are interested in. Given any natural number $N = a_{n}a_{n-1}\ldots a_{1}$ and some natural $p > 1$, we will designate a *p-remainder* number as any natural number which satisfies the next condition: 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}^{p} = a_{1}^{p} + a_{2}^{p} + \ldots + a_{n}^{p} \equiv 0\,\,(\text{mod}\,p)$$
It is quite easy to check the existence of p-remainders for any natural $p\geq 2$. It suffices to choose:
$$N_{p} = \sum_{k=0}^{p-1}10^{k} = \overbrace{11\ldots 1}^{p\,\text{times}}\Rightarrow 1^{p} + 1^{p} + \ldots + 1^{p} = p \Rightarrow 1^{p} + 1^{p} + \ldots + 1^{p}\equiv 0\,(\text{mod}\,p)$$

In this manner, we've just proved the existence of them for any natural number $p$ bigger than one. Once the definition makes sense, I would like to ask some questions. Firstly, could anyone provide any criterion to identify them quickly? Secondly, is there any chance to find out a formulae which
generates them all? I think this is it. Anyway, thank you in advance for any contribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $a^p \equiv a \pmod p$ if $p \not \mid a$ and $a^p \equiv 0 \pmod p$ if $p \mid a$. This comes from Fermat's Little Theorem. So using these we can determine when a number is a *p-remainder-number*. So a number is *p-remainder-number* iff the sum of all digits of the number that aren't divisible by $p$ is divisible by $p$.

For the second one I don't think that there exist a closed form, but here's a nice algorithm to generate a *p-remainder-number*. (Seemingly it generates them all). Take a partition of an integer multiple of $p$ such that all summands are positive and less than $10$. Now you can add as much zeroes or multiple of $p$ (as long as $p<10$) and now write the digits together. Maybe an example would be better. For example for $p=19$ we have:

$$1+3+7+0+8+0 \equiv 19 \equiv 0 \pmod{19} \implies 137080 \text{ is 19-remainder-number}$$

**UPDATE:** Although the OP didn't ask that question in particular we can calculate the number of $k-$digits *p-remainder-numbers* using stars and bars. For example if we want to calculate the number of 6- digits *19-remainder-numbers* by Stars and Bars and Inclusion-Exclusion we have that there are $\binom{24}{5} - 6\binom{14}{5}$ 6-digit numbers whose sum of digits is $19$. Now do the same for $38$, which is $\binom{43}{5} - 6\binom{33}{5} + 15\binom{23}{5} - 20\binom{13}{5}$ and add them.